# How to calculate with previous row value of a column if it can be declared only after it should be used in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The following is the dataframe I have:

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

todays_date = datetime.datetime.now().date()
index = pd.date_range(todays_date-datetime.timedelta(10), periods=10, freq='D')
data = pd.DataFrame(index=index)

data['Open'] = np.random.randint(20,40, size=len(data))
data['High'] = np.random.randint(40,50, size=len(data))
data['Low'] = np.random.randint(10,20, size=len(data))
data['Close'] = np.random.randint(10,20, size=len(data))
```

The calculations I would like to perform are the following:

```
capital = 30000

data['Shares'] = (capital * 0.05 / data['Close'].shift(1) - data['Low'].shift(1)).round(0)
data['Open_price'] = data['Open'] + 0.5 * (data['High'] - data['Open'])
data['Floating_P/L'] = data['Shares'] * data['Close']
data['Close_price'] = data['Close'] - 0.5 * (data['Close'] - data['Low'])
data['Closed_P/L'] = data['Shares'].shift(1) * data['Close_price']
data['Closed_Balance'] = capital + data['Closed_P/L'].cumsum()
data['Equity'] = data['Closed_Balance'] + data['Floating_P/L']

capital = data['Equity'].shift(1)
```

As you can see `Equity` is calculated from today's `Shares` number which is calculated from yesterday's `Equity`. I want to set `capital` to be the initial value of `Equity` at the first index and calculate `Shares` based on this number at the first index. From the second index, `Shares` should be calculated from the `Equity` shifted one row up. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have have given above, I see that initial value of `Shares` and first two values of `Equity` are `Nans` since first value of `Shares` is calculated using `Close` and `Low` columns shifted up. Assuming you can set up some values here,

try doing this?

1. Create empty columns in data for `Equity and Shares`

   ```
   data['Equity']=''
   data['Shares']=''
   ```
2. set `capital` to be the initial value of `Equity`. Since you mentioned initial value of `capital = 30000`

   ```
   capital= 30000
   data['Equity'][0]= 30000
   ```
3. Calculate initial value of `Shares`. Here try setting up values in place of `Nans` for `Close and Low`

   ```
   data['Shares'][0]= (capital * 0.05 / data['Close'].shift(1)[0] - data['Low'].shift(1))[0].round(0)
   ```
4. then use a for loop which iterates from second index to the length of data.